# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My code

```
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

object UIDStats {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Aadhaar dataset analysis using Spark")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
  import hiveContext.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Register dataset as a temp table
    val uidEnrolmentDF = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(args(0))
    uidEnrolmentDF.registerTempTable("uid_enrolments_detail")

    // Create a hive table with Total Aadhaar's generated for each state
    val stateWiseCountDF = hiveContext.sql("""
                                              | SELECT State, 
                                              |        SUM(`Aadhaar generated`) as count
                                              | FROM uid_enrolments_detail 
                                              | GROUP BY state 
                                              | ORDER BY count DESC""".stripMargin)

    stateWiseCountDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("uid.state_wise_count")


    // Create hive table with top 10 districts with maximum Aadhaar's generated for both Male and Female
    val districtWiseGenderCountDF = hiveContext.sql("""
                                                       | SELECT District, 
                                                       |        count(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 END) as male_count, 
                                                       |        count(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN 1 END) as FEMALE_count 
                                                       | FROM uid_enrolments_detail 
                                                       | GROUP BY District
                                                       | ORDER BY male_count DESC, FEMALE_count DESC
                                                       | LIMIT 10""".stripMargin)

    districtWiseGenderCountDF.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("uid.district_wise_gndr_count")
  }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;
    at com.aadharpoc.spark.UIDStats$.main(UIDStats.scala:20)
    at com.aadharpoc.spark.UIDStats.main(UIDStats.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/07/07 20:14:19 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

In this code databricks library is used to load the data from a csv file to a temp table.

after saving the code in the eclipse IDE  a stike through line is appearing on "HiveContext" and "registerTempTable". I can't understand this behaviour.

Please let me know where i am missing.
any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What's the build tool? sbt (recommended) or maven (ouch)? How did you define your project dependencies? Protip: a few screenshots could help a little.

Comment: hi Jack, I am using eclipse through which I downloaded scala IDE from market place. I had downloaded scala binaries and loaded them using external jars option in eclipse. Could you tell me you screenshots of which objects will help you to understand the error.

Comment: You should use sbt (or eventually maven or gradle) to manage your project dependencies. That's the recommended way to deal with external libraries like Spark. Otherwise, you'd have to add all Spark libs to Scala IDE manually (highly discouraged). BTW, use IntelliJ IDEA. Much better coding experience!

Comment: So as per your analysis, the issue might be with the dependencies? I had explained my flow in my earlier comment right based on that could you advise me where sbt to comes into the game? I am doing all these in the cloudera quickstart vm.

Comment: Start from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: I had the same issue. initially I was building the  JAR file using maven  ( spark 1.6, scala 2.11.0 ) and running it on Spark 2.4.0.  I changed the  spark version to 2.4.0  in the maven pom and rebuilt JAR file still same issue. Later on I switched to SBT with spark version 2.4.0 and scala version 2.11.0  and built  new JAR. The issue went away.